# why pop_back just removes the last element

Tags: c++

Generally to get the last element and remove it 
 I have to use `stl::back` and then the `stl::pop_back`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    // Create a vector containing integers
    std::vector<int> v = {7, 5, 16, 8};

    // Add two more integers to vector
    auto x= v.back();
    v.pop_back();

    std::cout<<"last value removed was"<<x<<"\n";
    // Iterate and print values of vector
    for(int n : v) {
        std::cout << n << '\n';
    }
}
```

Is there a way or any other stl by which I can use the pop_back() returns the last element and then remove .Just use a single stl

why is pop_back() just implemented to remove it would have been better if it could return as well .Any reason it is implemented just to remove

Comment: Exception safety.

Comment: Did you mean `std::vector::back` and `std::vector::pop_back`? Unless `stl` is the namespace by some other library you didn't mention.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  My bad yes I mean to say std::vector::back